# Calculating difference between daily revenue and budget with Power BI (DirectQuery)

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

Using Direct Query I am trying to calculate the difference between budgeted and actual revenue per day, working with a monthly budget that is recorded on the first day of each month.

We have managed to calculate the size of the budget per day for each month, dividing the monthly budget by the number of working days that month. Due to the limitations of Direct Query we use a slicer as an input where one can choose the correct number of working days from a list.

We want to be able to subtract the calculated budget per day from the actual revenue that day. Working with data from Entity Store using DirectQuery, our possibilities are limited and we can not add new tables.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is a sample of what we have been able to make so far:

[image: Sample table]

We are using the following tables:

[image: Revenue table]

[image: Budget table]

[image: #OfWorkDays table]

We are also using a standard date table.

Here is the link to a full description of the problem including suggested solutions:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-deviation-between-revenue-and-daily-budget-with/m-p/560861/highlight/true#M264794

Thanks,
Carina

Comment: You need to put some examples with sample data. Read the community standards for question posting.

Comment: This doesn't address your main question, but why don't you use a column on your date table to indicate which days are working days to remove the need for the slicer with the number of working days. Your calculated budget per day would then need to count the number of working days in the month. This has the advantage, though, that you can get it to show zero budget on non-working days.

Comment: The post is now updated with sample data. That is a good idea, but as working days and holidays move from year to year (and our date table consists of several thousand rows) it is not that easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your daily budget measure:

```
Daily Budget =
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Revenue[Actual Revenue]),
        STARTOFMONTH(Revenue[Date])
    ),
    SELECTEDVALUE(NumberOfWorkDays[NumberOfWorkDays], 1)
)
```

Then your deviation measure can simply be:

```
Deviation = SUM(Revenue[Actual Revenue]) - [Daily Budget]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution, but it still doesn't work. I think the problem might be that in the budget table the only date is the first of each month, as that is when the budget is recorded. We tried to copy and merge the date and the budget table to get all dates into the budget table - but that changes the storage mode to import mode, which we cannot work with in this case.

Comment: It worked fine when I tried to replicate it. Can you share a PBIX?